Sample size for REPEATED MEASURES ANOVA
I am calculating a required sample size for the Repeated Measures ANOVA (within subject). I came across two different packages and the results are different.
Using "WebPower" package and the following function
wp.rmanova(n = NULL, ng = 1, nm = 4, f = 0.25, nscor = 1, 
           alpha = 0.05, power = 0.8, type = 1)

I obtained this result:
Repeated-measures ANOVA analysis

           n    f ng nm nscor alpha power
    175.7464 0.25  1  4     1  0.05   0.8

NOTE: Power analysis for within-effect test
URL: http://psychstat.org/rmanova

Using "pwrss" package and the following function
pwrss.f.rmanova(eta2 = 0.06,  n.levels = 1, n.rm = 4, power = 0.80, 
                alpha = 0.05, corr.rm = 0.50, type = "within")

I obtained this result:
 One-way Repeated Measures 
 Analysis of Variance (F test) 
 H0: eta2 = 0 (or f2 = 0) 
 HA: eta2 > 0 (or f2 > 0) 
 ------------------------------ 
 Number of levels (groups) = 1 
 Number of repeated measurements = 4 
 ------------------------------ 
  Statistical power = 0.8 
  Total n = 23 
 ------------------------------ 
 Type of the effect = “within” 
 Numerator degrees of freedom = 3 
 Denominator degrees of freedom = 65.029 
 Non-centrality parameter = 11.579 
 Type I error rate = 0.05 
 Type II error rate = 0.2 

I also used GPower to compare the results and I also obtained different sample sizes based on different effect size specification. When I used the default GPower3 effect size specification I obtained n = 24.

Using the Cohen's effect size specification I obtained n = 176.

There was also an "SPSS" option which gave me a sample size of 61. I also read that if you take Cohen's calculation a divide the n by number of measurements - 1 and add the number of groups you'll get to the SPSS sample size calculation which agrees: 176/(4-1) + 1 = 60. Can anyone please advise which approach is correct? The difference in these calculations is massive ranging from 24 to 176.

I'm not super familiar with any of these functions, but it looks like Gpower and wp.rmanova are using a correlation of 0 and pwrss is using 0.5? I don't understand what you're saying about the SPSS option - where did you read this?

I'd do a simulation. I also wouldn't use RM Anova, because it has some weird idiosyncracies in things like sphericity assumptions.

So it looks like when you have a correlation of 0.5, you get 24, and when you don't, you get 176. It's not clear to me why one of the GPower screenshots has an option for the correlation and the other does not.

Also, what does f = 0.25 mean? Where is that from?

Reading https://webpower.psychstat.org/wiki/manual/power_of_rmanova#effect_size it appears that webpower expects you to incorporate the correlation into the effect size. Gpower (second one) does not, and presumably pwrss.f.rmanova() does not.

I don't think Cohen talked about effect sizes for repeated measures studies and didn't define effect sizes for them.
In a repeated measures study, the correlation between the measures has a dramatic effect on the power of the test, and this effect increases with the number of measurements.
Different authors appear to define the effect size ($f$) differently. Some of them define it as:
$f = \frac{\sigma(m)}{\sigma}$
And in this case you are required to enter the correlation between the measures (which I guess assumed to be equal for all correlations).
Others define it as
$f = \frac{\sigma(m)}{\sigma} \times C$
Where C is based on the correlation between the measures.
$C = \sqrt{\frac{K}{1 - \rho}}$
So when you use $f = 0.25$ in the power analysis, this is sometimes assuming a correlation of 0 (in which case you need 176 responses for 80% power), and sometimes you are explicitly telling it to use a correlation of 0.5.
If you need to adjust the effect size for the correlation, you should use an effect size of 0.707, not 0.25. If you do that, you should find that your analyses match.
Notice that your power is highly dependent on the correlation that you provide. You should under-estimate rather than over-estimate this value, to ensure that your power analysis is conservative.
(But this is the problem with using arbitrary effect sizes - what does 0.25 mean for your data?)

So, can we not refer to Cohen for effect sizes in repeated measures studies (e.g., if
=0.26 in G*POWER with a 0.5 correlation, then medium?) due to the correlation factor?

Whether you can, and whether you should are different things.  Did you pick medium effect size for any particular reason, or just because it was medium? Cohen wrote about the effect size conventions “these values are necessarily somewhat arbitrary, but were chosen so as to seem reasonable".   You might find this article useful: https://www.frontiersin.org/journals/psychology/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2019.00813/full .  I use the Cohen conventions as a measure of last resort - when I have no other idea. One problem is that the same amount of change can have a different effect, with different SD.

Thank you! If I want to use a correlation of 0.5 and expect a medium effect size, should I input f=0.25 in GPower's default option, with the transformation to Cohen's being approximately 0.707, or should I input f=0.25 into Cohen's option for the effect size, which would then transform to an f=0.0883883 for GPower's default option?
